# Creating a synthetic camera in vtk and manipulating the intrinsic parameters and extrinsic interactively

Tags: vtk

I want to render a scene interactively. The controls are already provided so that you can position the camera with mouse but you never know the exact value.

I want to manipulate the internal camera values as well e.g focal length.

Externally I want to set the translation and rotation of the camera.

I want to give all the values manually. Could anyone please help to point to such a demo or a code snippet to do it. Preferably in python.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the camera from the renderer with renderer->GetActiveCamera(). Then you can manipulate it using the class functions: http://www.vtk.org/doc/nightly/html/classvtkCamera.html

Here is a simple Python example: http://www.vtk.org/Wiki/VTK/Examples/Python/Camera

Comment: The example does not show how to manipulate camera intrinsic values such as focal length, do you know how to do this?

Comment: @Aly, if you set your actor at the origin, you can create a focal length like this:

camera->SetPosition(f_x, f_y, f_z); // f_x, f_y... are the focal distance in each direction, usually you would set it on a specific axis and give it a specific focal length:

camera->SetPosition(0, focal_length, 0);